# Seeking a noun for "a condescending, didactic, long-winded speech or soliloquy"

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, word-usage

- Looking for a noun
- Intended meaning:  “a condescending, didactic, long-winded speech or soliloquy for the purpose of one’s own self-aggrandizement”
- Prefer it not to end in (-tion)

Below are my initial attempts starting with the closest match.
Connotations in parentheses.

**Closest:**

1. Bloviation (long-winded, inflated, empty, pompous, arrogant)
2. Pontification (pompous, dogmatic)

**Not as good:**

1. Diatribe, Harangue, Tirade (overemphasis on anger and criticism)
2. Gasconade (overemphasis on boastfulness as opposed to condescension and didacticism)
3. Jeremiad (overemphasis on complaint)
4. Prattle, Chatter, Witter, Babble  (overemphasis on triviality)
5. Bombast (pompous, grandiloquent)(refers to the manner of speech not the speech itself “Bombast made the speech intolerable” – not “She delivered a bombast”)

Comment: A ***Polonialism*** :). LORD POLONIUS: “This business is well ended.
My liege, and madam, to expostulate
What majesty should be, what duty is,
Why day is day, night night, and time is time,
Were nothing but to waste night, day, and time.
Therefore, since brevity is the soul of wit,
And tediousness the limbs and outward flourishes,
I will be brief: your noble son is mad:
Mad call I it; for, to define true madness,
What is’t but to be nothing else but mad?
But let that go.”

Comment: Every Saturday and Sunday morning, millions call it a ***sermon***.

Comment: Have you considered '***filibuster***'?

Comment: I think you covered all the good ones.  I'd suggest combining a few, such as "pompous prattle".

Comment: 'Filibuster' is a prolonged speech used as a delaying tactic. It is neither 'didactic' nor 'condescending', as was asked in the question.

Answer (score 3):

You can consider ***rodomontade***.

> A vainglorious brag or boast; an extravagantly boastful, arrogant, or bombastic speech or piece of writing *[OED]*

An example from *OED*:

> 1862     Thackeray *Adventures of Philip* I. viii. 144     Phil used to bore *me* after dinner with endless rodomontades about his passion and his charmer; but my wife was never tired of listening.

Etymology of the word from *[Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=rodomontade)*:

> 1610s (earlier *rodomontado*, 1590s), "vain boasting like that of Rodomonte," character in Ariosto's "Orlando Furioso." In dialectal Italian the name means literally "one who rolls (away) the mountain."

Note: *Rodomontado* is a synonym and partly from Italian *rodomontata* and partly an alteration of *rodomontade*, after *-ado* suffix.

Answer (score 0):

"**Bloviate**" is  [slang](https://books.google.ca/books?id=hc7x96jE5EcC&pg=PA58&dq=slang%20Bloviation&hl=en&sa=X&ei=issWVeC0MLTLsAS214GgBQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=slang%20Bloviation&f=false) and not elegant enough (see the 2nd example on the linked page).

Other candidates: **denounce,  to indulge in 'high falutin', harangue, hold forth, inveigh, condescend**.

Comment: "high falutin" is probably the closest to what he wants, its only faults are are that it's usually used by speakers to highlight a self-deprecating class distinction in addition to being informal (which is related to the first issue).

Denounce, harangue, and inveigh all carry connotations of hostility and anger. But good finds.

Answer (score -1):

Excellent job doing your own research prior to asking!

I know you want one word that encompasses "a condescending, didactic, long-winded speech or soliloquy." I can't find anything better than what you've already found. But here's an idea that might work for you, depending on what you're writing: Just find a synonym for "speech" that sounds like a big college word, and then let the context add all those other nuances of meaning for you.

Example words: lecture, discourse, treatise, allocution, disquisition, dissertation.

For example:

> At recess, Billy stopped the other children in the midst of a roaring
>   game of Alien Invasion, and when he had their attention, he stood atop
>   the teeter-totter and gave his usual discourse on the Fermi Paradox
>   and the Rare Earth Hypothesis, explaining that their game lacked a
>   scientific basis.

Comment: These are not direct answers; ELU is not a discussion forum. This suggestion would be better as a comment.